# Is it possible to deploy an Azure Web App based on a public git repo using only an ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-git-deployment

I'm looking for a way to deploy an Azure Web App based on a public git repo containing a .NET, .NET Core, or Node service. However, I want to only use an ARM template to deploy the Web App.

So if I have a public repo that contains a .NET Core project (i.e., csproj and associated C# files), I want to deploy a Web App, using an ARM template, that will deploy from the repo. It seems like it's possible with the various options for continuous deployment, but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is, you need to define the sourcecontrol property of the webapp for that to happen, like in [this](https://github.com/4c74356b41/bbbb-is-the-word/blob/master/_arm/webapp-git.json#L142) example:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
    "name": "web",
    "type": "sourcecontrols",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('siteName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoURL')]",
        "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",
        "IsManualIntegration": true
    }
}
```